# Why Python round-off is different from the excel round off? How to get the same result

Tags: python, excel, rounding

I am facing an issue with python round-off.

Input value = 3.7145,
which I have tried in excel with the

```
formula: =round(C9/1000,6)
```

and I get the
**Output = 0.003715,**

Same thing when I tried with Python with the below code:

**Python Code:**

```
number = 3.7145
result = round(number / 1000, 6)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
0.003714
```

How to ensure that we get exact same value, as my requirement is a high precision so even a .000001 variation is not allowed.
I have tried same with other number also where I get the same values in excel and python

```
Input : 1.0127, 2.3216, 5.4938
Output: 0.001013, 0.002322, 0.005494 (Same in python & excel)
```

Comment: What *are* your rounding requirements? "Do whatever Excel does"? "Just be reproducible"? "Round ties away from zero"? Something else?

Comment: Are you sure the output is what it is? What is prints on the screen is not necessarily what is stored. Subtract `0.003714` from your python output and the result is likely not zero. Also: Excel does weird stuff to get the "expected" result. You probably won't be able to reproduce that in python.

Comment: Your sentence about `as my requirement is a high precision so even a ... variation is not allowed` is contradictory with the fact you are rounding your number. If you want better precision, do not round them

Comment: @Nathan Agreed. Probably worth noting that a Python *float* data type is inappropriate for high precision in the first place

Comment: Python 2 should give the same results. But Python 3 is using a different rounding algorithm for floats. At the mid-point, Excel will round away from zero, but Python3 (and VBA .Round, for that matter) will round towards the nearest even number (which is actually a better algorithm). I believe you will need a custom Python function to change this rounding behavior. Suggest you read Wikipedia regarding rounding algorithms. Also search this forum for articles on how to change the behavior in Python3.

Comment: In Python 3 you should be able to use the decimal module and change the rounding mode to `ROUND_HALF_UP`. (see documentation regarding `Context`). This will then mimic the Excel worksheet rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get better precision you should use `Decimal` instead of `Float`

**Python Code**

```py
from decimal import Decimal

number = Decimal("3.7145")
result = number / 1000
print(round(result, 6))
```

**Output**

```py
0.003715
```

### Edit  2021.06.05 17:51 UTC

Changed `number = Decimal(3.7145)` to `number = Decimal("3.7145")`

As @RonRosenfeld mentioned in a comment creating `number` as `Decimal(3.7145)` includes inaccuracy of floating point from `3.7145` float number

Comment: But the question is, will that match Excel in all cases?  Does Excel use decimal arithmetic?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not sure about what Excel uses. Even if I were, I would be far from be 100% sure if it will always match Excel results (especially with precisions above 28th place). I think the question is not if it always will match Excel (because then we would assume that Excel always produces correct results and not approximation). The backbone of the question (for me) is how to correctly handle calculation in python that require high precision.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for results that match, not higher accuracy.  The title even says "same result".  There are plenty of people who consider Excel the gold standard, whether it deserves that or not.

Comment: What you think is happening is not what is really happening. When you convert `3.7145` to a decimal, you include the FP inaccuracies and it actually converts to `3.71450000000000013500311979441903531551361083984375`. When you divide by 1000 and round to 6, it rounds to .003715 because the value being rounded is greater than than `.0037145`. If you want to convert to decimal with four digit precision, you will need to convert the string `"3.7145"`. Since Python 3 rounds to even, you would see the result `0.003714`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that's a very good point. Thank you for pointing it out, will update my answer with the annotation.

Comment: If you want to mimic Excel, I suggest that you also change the Context rounding mode from the default `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` to `ROUND_HALF_UP`